# how to prevent or extend AppleEvent or SpeechRecognitionServer timed out?

Tags: applescript, runtime-error, speech-recognition, applescript-objc, appleevents

I am working on a SpeechRecognition project and I am pretty much done. However, there is one thing I cant quite figure out. When I launch my application it listens to my commands, and if I stay quite or don't say the commands then it is giving me this Script Error:
[image]
it is timing out. I want it to stay open 24 hour even if I am not saying anything.

This is my code:

```
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
    with timeout of 10000 seconds
        set FRIDAY_AI to listen for commands
    end timeout
end tell
```

If you could help me solve this problem I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: You might try `listen continuously for`, giving it an identifier to use with `stop listening for identifier` - that is a pretty big download for me.

Comment: Can you go explain little more, maybe with examples of what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have that 1.2GB download to run speech recognition, but take a look at SpeechRecognitionServer's scripting dictionary for the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 70% of everything I do on my computer is controlled by dictation commands and my own custom dictation commands. Very powerful stuff once you get the hang of it. I set you up with a small script with a few examples to have the SpeechRecognitionServer app continuously listen for a set of spoken commands to act upon.  I think it's pretty self-explanatory by looking at the code to be able to adjust it to your needs.

In Script Editor, save this following code as a stay open application.  Make sure to add your new app in System Preferences to the list of apps allowed to control your computer.  Now all you need to do is launch your new app.

```
on idle
    try
        tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
            set theChoice to listen continuously for ¬
                {"Open Google", "Close Windows", "Enter Name", "Enter Password", "Close My Commands"} ¬
                    with identifier "mine" with section title "WeeeHaaa's Commands"

            if theChoice is "Open Google" then
                tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
            else if theChoice is "Close Windows" then
                tell application "Finder" to close windows
            else if theChoice is "Enter Name" then
                set myFullname to "Crazy Eddie"
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke myFullname
                end tell
            else if theChoice is "Enter Password" then
                set myPassword to "secretpassword"
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke myPassword
                end tell
            else if theChoice is "Close My Commands" then
                quit me
            end if

        end tell
    end try
    return 0.5
end idle

on quit
    -- stop listening
    tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
        stop listening for identifier "mine"
    end tell
    continue quit
end quit
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for this code! I tried it and when I ran it, it quits in less than a second. It ends as soon as I run it.

Comment: i've add it to the list of apps that can control my computer. I've added "continuously" to my original code and got this ERROR: SpeechRecognitionServer got an error: {"copy the link", "paste the link", "give me list of running apps", "open a folder", "open chrome"} doesn’t understand the “listen continuously for” message.

Comment: Okay let's try isolating the problem.  Save the code in my post, exactly as it is, in Script Editor app as a "Stay Open" application.  Without saving it as a "Stay Open" Application, it won't work. Running the code through Script Editor app Will not work either.  Run the application as you would run any other application... Double click on it in Finder.  Your dictation commands window with your custom commands should be open now.  Now speak some of those commands to see if they work.   It should not make a difference whether you have enhanced dictation commands enabled or not.

Comment: If the above-mentioned steps work, go back to Script Editor, making sure your stay open application is no longer running, and replace one of my commands with one of yours.  Re-save that file in Script Editor. Once again, in Finder, double click app and test the commands again

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!! Thank you so MUCH!!!!! I really appreciate the fact that you took your time and help me solve this problem, again, thank you!